# Deleting PDF file after printing in Java

Tags: java, pdf, file-io, itext

I'm trying to delete a PDF file after printing. The PDF is generated using JAVA code and needs to be deleted after the printing process is carried out. However, I am facing an issue while deleting the file. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

The error shown while trying to delete the file from its folder is:
***"File in Use: The Action can't be completed because the file is open in Java(TM) Platform SE Binary."***

The code I've used is as follows:

```
public String actionPrintReport() {
    try {

    // Creates a new document object
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);

    File file = new File(fileLocation.concat("\\".concat(fileName)));
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);

    // Creates a pdfWriter object for the FILE
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fo);

    // Open the document
    document.open();

    // Add meta data...

    // Insert Data...

    // Close the document
    document.close();

    // Create a PDFFile from a File reference
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    FileChannel fc = fis.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());

    PDFFile pdfFile = new PDFFile(bb); 

    // Create PDF Print Page
    PDFPrintPage pages = new PDFPrintPage(pdfFile);

    // Create Print Job...

    // Close
    fo.flush();
    fo.close();
    fis.close();

    if (file.exists()) {
        if (file.delete()) {
        String check = "yes";
        } else {
        String check = "no";
            }
    }

    // Send print job to default printer
    pjob.print();
    actionMsg = "success";
    return SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ERROR;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not put the deletion in a finally block?

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
   if (file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
   }
}
```

After discussion with the OP, an approach was investigated to use [Apache FileCleaningTracker](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/io/FileCleaningTracker.html) whereby the File is tracked and then deleted after a Monitored Object has been GC'd.

Comment: I tried doing that as well but it doesn't seem to work. the 'file' variable shows the correct path, but it still doesn't seem to be deleting.

Comment: try closing the PdfWriter

Comment: I tried that and closing the file channel as well but it still isn't deleting.

Comment: so are you sure that `file.delete ()` is being called?  If are 100% then try using http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/io/FileCleaningTracker.html

Comment: If the delete function is being called, then would it be tracked by the cleaning tracker? Because I used this but the track counter is showing 0.

Comment: you need to use the `track` method

Comment: I haven't really used this before. What would I need to do with the object marker?

Comment: It looks like the object marker is any local object.  The idea being that when this object gets removed due to gc, then it can be safely assumed that the file can be deleted.  See also `getDeleteFailures`

Comment: So I'd just need to create a new object and when the object is removed the file would consequently be deleted? Then it would mean that some amount of time would be required before the file is actually deleted, would it not?

Comment: In you case you could maybe use your `document` object or maybe even `this`.  Yes some amount of time is required before the object is removed.

Comment: After explicitly calling System.gc() the file is deleted but is calling it everytime recommended?

Comment: a call to `System.gc` is just recommending to the system to do a GC and it may or may not actually do one.  Whether you should or not I can not say based upon what I know (nothing) about your System.  Is it so necessary to delete the file immediately, if not do not call System.gc

Comment: Thanks. I removed the System.gc() and turns out that after printing out a 4-5 files the files are deleted automatically. Thanks for all the help

Comment: I'll update the answer, but I suggest that you update it by adding a summary of what is said in the comments. This will improve the quality of the answer and help people with the same problem (who may overlook the comments).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks Bruno, I have done so. Mr ncdreamy may want to accept this answer.

Comment: Thanks for improving the answer using the appropriate comment. I agree: Mr ncdreamy should accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks! @ScaryWombat